# Import data from .exp file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have received a .exp file from a third party source , which it mentions can be used with MySQL.
How do I use data dump files with .exp extension in MySQL

Comment: Please share more details - what does that file contain? The extension alone does not tell you anything about the content. Also, please explain how this is related to programming

Answer (score 1):

The only .exp file extension I know of is for Percona Server 5.5, a branch of MySQL. These files aren't data dumps. They are metadata files for InnoDB tablespace exports created by the Percona XtraBackup tool.

Read about how to export and import here: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/management/innodb_expand_import.html

It's not the most convenient feature. It requires you to do multiple steps by hand to import these files.

The `.exp` file alone is useless. You also need a `.ibd` file to go with it, and you need the table definitions (the CREATE TABLE statements).